# Sapper loading pages underneath each other

Tags: html, node.js, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I have a sapper/svelte app that when I navigate from my profile page to another page (let's say home) the home page loads underneath the profile page for a split second. Then loads normally.

Before clicking to go home:

[image]

After clicking home page link: 
[image]

This is crazy to me and I have no idea whats going on??

After a split second, the profile page disappears and the home page displays correctly.

Comment: How can anybody give you assistance if you don't provide code, context, etc.?

Comment: @ThomasHennes There is nothing special goin on. Not much code to show it's just navigation around a sapper app

Comment: I'm not sure why people disliked this question.. it is a good question and I'm also coming across this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation could be that you use `transition`s on the pages’ outer elements.

When using, for example, the `fade` transition provided by Svelte, elements that are fading in and out at the same time (e .g. in order to replace each other) will both be visible for the duration of the transition.

To avoid this behavior, you need to add a `delay` on the element that is fading in, corresponding to the duration of the fade out transition. This will cause the new element to only be visible when the old element has already been removed from the DOM.

As an example:

```
<main in:fade={{ delay: 100, duration: 100 }} out:fade={{ duration: 100}}>
```

Please see the [Svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#transition_fn) for more information on transition parameters.

Comment: Yes, apparently any 'out' transition no matter how deep in the tree the node is will affect un-mounting parent DOM elements. This has to be a bug in svelte. But this could be a solution. Thank you

Comment: I think you can use the `local` modifier to prevent this: “Local transitions only play when the block they belong to is created or destroyed, not when parent blocks are created or destroyed.” [Svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Transition_events)